# Mensaje de error personalizado al intentar insertar valor duplicado

Tags: c#, sql-server

En sql hice que el campo documento de mi base de datos fuera único para evitar que registren un cliente dos veces y el sistema evita que ocurra sin embargo capturo la excepción mediante un try catch en c# y el mensaje que arroja no es un mensaje que el usuario entienda. me refiero a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer para poner un mensaje personalizado en el try catch?

osea en esta parte del código:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

y aqui el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que el problema esta en que son dos excepciones internas:

**Excepción interna 1:**
UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

**Excepción interna 2:**
SqlException: Infracción de la restricción UNIQUE KEY 'IX_Paciente'. No se puede insertar una clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.Paciente'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (092-3423423-4).

como hago para que solo muestre la segunda o en su defecto que las muestre ambas, si al usuario le sale la 2da es facil que entienda donde se equivoco pero la primera no dice nada

Comment: Antes del  catch (Exception ex) puede utilizar un catch (SqlException sqlEx) y avirguar lo que pasó con ése.

Comment: No es mas facil verificar si el cliente ya existe y de ser asi mostrar un mensaje.

Comment: Por ejemplo: antes de agregar el cliente verifica si el mismo ya existe, create una funcion o metodo que realize esa verificacion y que retorne un boleano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto

```
try{
  ....
}
catch (SqlException ex) {
            if (ex.Number == 544) {
                MessageBox.Show(Window, "No se puede insertar duplicados", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
 }
```

Puedes buscar la lista de errores en 
[Full List of System Error Messages in SQL Server 2017](https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2017/error_messages/)

Para depurar (BreakPoint) le das click en la barrita de la izquierda como en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización

Ya pude tengo un proyecto con EntityFramework y parece que ya funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex) {


                        if (ex.InnerException.InnerException is SqlException) {
                            SqlException sql = (SqlException)ex.InnerException.InnerException;
                            if (sql.Number == 2627) {
                                MessageBox.Show(this, "No se puede insertar duplicados", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: al parecer no es el 544 porque sigue saliendo. como puedo depurarlo para que me arroje el error?

Comment: Puedes poner tu código porfa, saludos

Comment: lo deje en forma de respuesta

Comment: Pues parece bien el código, pon un breakpoint en el if del catch para ver que número trae

Comment: el breakpoint se lo vuela, solo salta el mensaje de error. influye en algo el hecho de usar entity framework?

Comment: Si se lo salta quiere decir que la Exception no es de tipo SqlException, si ussas entity framework porque no checas si existe antes de guardarlo?

Comment: Puedes obtener el mensaje asi `catch (Exception ex) {
                        var a = ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
                    }`

Comment: intente con MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message); pero sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje plano y cuando puse el tuyo no sale nada

Comment: Puedes intentar con lo que puse arriba.

Comment: ahora si funciona muchas gracias, lo que estaba haciendo era ponerlo directamente como mensaje pero en ese caso aunque no fuera por duplicado daria ese error. con la actualizacion en tu respuesta me funciono

Comment: una duda, de que le sirve al usuario saber que no se pueden insertar duplicados, mostrarle eso o un mensaje en ingles que no entienda es exactamente lo mismo

Answer (score 2):

Podrias simplemente loguear en un archivo el mensaje que recibes del exception y luego al usuario le muestras un moensaje estandar

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    MessageBox.Show("Se ha producir un error con la base de datos");
}
```

Por supuesto despues debes valir el archivo de log para ver que sucedio

[Flexible, structured events — log file convenience.](https://serilog.net/)

puedes usar librerias como ser `sirilog`

[Serilog nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog/)

de esta forma puede separar el mensaje tecnico sin perderlo y mostrar al usario un mensaje que tu definas mas amigable

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que requieres es mostrarle al usuario el mensaje de que se esta intentando agregar un registro que ya existe, podrías hacerlo con un switch con los diferentes códigos de error.

Ejemplo:

```
try{

}
catch (SqlException ex) {
    //Log.Error(ex.Message, ex)
    switch (ex.Number )
    {
        case 2627: 
            MessageBox.Show("Es posible que la información ya se encuentra registrada");
        default:

            MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar realizar operación en BD.");
    }        
}
```

Comment: log.error no me lo reconoce. ni me da posibles opciones de importar librerias con usign es algun complemento extra?

Comment: puedes agregar el paquete  log4net para el manejo de logs